# How do I fix "package solana-program v1.18.0 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer"?

Tags: solana-program, build-bpf, rustc, build-sbf

When building an onchain program with `cargo build-sbf` using `solana-program` v1.18, I get the following error:

```
error: package solana-program v1.18.0 cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
```

I'm using v1.17.17 of the CLI:

```
$ cargo build-sbf -V
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.17.17
platform-tools v1.37
rustc 1.68.0
$ solana -V
solana-cli 1.17.17 (src:27a43800; feat:1337574167, client:SolanaLabs)
```

How can I resolve this?

(inspired by https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/34987)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few options to fix the build:

#### Use a command line argument to specify a version of the build tools

As of `cargo build-sbf` that comes bundled with Solana v1.16, you can use the `--tools-version` argument to use a different version of the build tools. Version 1.39 of the build tools contains a Rust compiler at 1.72, so you can run:

```
cargo build-sbf --tools-version v1.39
```

#### Upgrade to Solana tools 1.18

Upgrade to the Solana 1.18 tools, which defaults to v1.39 of the build tools:

```
solana-install init 1.18.0
```

Note at the time of writing Anchor was not ready for 1.18.

#### Set your solana-program version

As a last ditch effort, you can set your build to use v1.17 of `solana-program` by specifying the version in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
cargo add solana-program@"=1.17"
```

This is recommended by [Solana Rust getting started Guide](https://solana.com/developers/guides/getstarted/local-rust-hello-world).

If you intend to publish your program crate, it will be much harder for others to use, forcing them onto exactly one version of `solana-program`. If any other crate in the build does the same thing, then it will be impossible to build.