# cargo build-bpf package error: `ahash v0.8.8` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, rustc

I'm using a simple hello world solana program from https://moralis.io/how-to-write-a-solana-smart-contract

src/lib.rs

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::AccountInfo,
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    msg,
};
entrypoint!(process_instruction);
pub fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8]
) -> ProgramResult {
    msg!("Hello, world!");
    Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "hello_world"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
solana-program = "1.18.2"

[lib]
name = "hello_world"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

```
$ cargo build-bpf
error: package `ahash v0.8.8` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.72.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.72.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p ahash@0.8.8 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `ahash` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
```

Additional info:

```
$ cargo-build-sbf --version
solana-cargo-build-sbf 1.17.22
platform-tools v1.37
rustc 1.68.0

$ rustc --version
rustc 1.72.1 (d5c2e9c34 2023-09-13)

$ solana --version
solana-cli 1.17.22 (src:dbf06e25; feat:3580551090, client:SolanaLabs)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error building program with \`solana-program\` v1.18 and CLI v1.17](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/error-building-program-with-solana-program-v1-18-and-cli-v1-17)

Comment: yes it does. thanks!