# cargo build-bpf error with rustc version

Tags: rust, version

When I execute the command cargo build-bpf, I encounter an error. How can I resolve this issue?

`` error: package `libp2p-allow-block-list v0.3.0 (https://github.com/sigp/rust-libp2p/?rev=cfa3275ca17e502799ed56e555b6c0611752e369#cfa3275c)` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.73.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.72.0-dev Either upgrade to rustc 1.73.0 or newer, or use cargo update -p libp2p-allow-block-list@0.3.0 --precise ver where `ver` is the latest version of `libp2p-allow-block-list` supporting rustc 1.72.0-dev ``

```
solana-cli:1.18.4
rustc: 1.76.0
rustup: 1.26.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/9799/84: if you need to use a newer version of the Solana Rust compiler, you can use the `--tools-version` argument. In your case, you can try:

```
cargo build-sbf --tools-version v1.41
```